# How to know if a flag used by preprocessor (like #ifdef or #if) is indeed defined or not

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was diving into the glibc source code and found quite a lot of usages of preprocessors like

```
#ifdef XXX
```

and

```
#if YYY
```

In order to know the exact behavior of the glibc that will be compiled and run on my machine, I have to know whether these flags are indeed defined or not. What I am currently doing is to insert the following piece of code to somewhere, compile, and run, which is neither elegant nor efficient.

```
#ifdef XXX
printf("XXX defined");
#endif
```

Anther way might be to `grep` the flag in the entire source tree, but I found this way not very reliable. Because sometimes I didn't find any `#define XXX` but I still got `XXX defined` printed out. (Can anyone let me know why?)

Therefore, I want to know what is the best practice to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I found that combination of `gcc` with `-g3` and `gdb` is pretty useful for checking macros and even macro-expansions for function-like macros. See `man gcc` and [12 C Preprocessor Macros](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html) from GDB manual for more details.

As more "invasive" way you could put [`#pragma message`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) (or some similar) directive to examine individual macros during compilation:

> Prints string as a compiler message on compilation. The message is
>   informational only, and is neither a compilation warning nor an error.

There is also `-E` switch, that allows to simply look into preprocessed translation unit.